# If all ajax are not done and user leaves the window or page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a script that starts after all ajax is done. I am trying to modify the script and add a condition like `if ajax is not done AND user left the windows then trigger function`. Is this possible?

```
var isDone=false;
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    if(isDone) {
        return; 
    } else {
        isDone=true;
        $.post("lib/ajax.html", { action: 'update_date', domain: domain });
    }
    //if(isDone == false && ) if ajax is not done and user leaves page 
    // exits then post to update date
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a user leaves a page, use the following function and within that check the `isDone` flag:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
  if(!isDone) {
   <<execute function>>
  }
});
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.active to check if any ajax request is pending right now or not. And then use

```
$(window).unload(function(){
 if ($.active > 0) {
       //Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason unload is not working http://jsfiddle.net/L4qcah52/. Check when the user closes the window it should echo the message bad.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using th unload-function of jQuery (which is deprecated in version 1.8) I would recommend using the native javscript here:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if(!isDone) {
      //do something or if you want the user to confirm that he want to leave:
      return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
    }
}
```

**[onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload)**

Note: This function is no part of any standard so there can be different behaviours in different browser and versions.

Comment: @user3467855 try `onbeforeunload` instead, this works (at least in FF)

Comment: @user3467855 try opening your fiddle, add some characters (a blank should be enough) in the javascript-section and press `run` in the fiddle and then close the tab. It is working fine in my browser

Comment: @user3467855 try it with a blank after a closing bracket, this should be enough

Comment: That is the jsfiddle website message, the message You have... http://jsfiddle.net/wqmhLjc0/6/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65512/discussion-between-user3467855-and-empiric).

Answer (score 0):

If it is important to post that information, I would let the server script post its status to the update_date script instead.

The server is likely to finish the request, even when the user closes the browser, and that way you don't depend on the user/browser.

People *will* be able to close their browser. They could even kill the browser process if you try to block them.